# Unable to integrate 3-legged OAuth with XACML

Tags: oauth, wso2

I'm trying to use WSO2 Identity server for OAuth token management for my own web application.

I exactly follow the instructions in [this blog post](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2011/07/integrating-3-legged-oauth-with-xacml.html) and downloaded WSO2 identity server 3.2.3, wso2esb 4.0.3, wso2as 4.1.2 in Ubuntu 10.04. I successfully got the access token.

However, when I ran the code in the last part of the blog in Eclipse(I've already used the correct CONSUMER_SECRET,CONSUMER_KEY and OAUTH_TOKEN in the code), I ended up with an error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:409)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:240)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:321)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:338)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:935)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:876)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:801)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:488)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:515)
    at org.wso2.rest.security.oauth.OauthClient.main(OauthClient.java:44)
```

I'm sure the service port is available and can't figure out what the problem is. Could anyone provide any help?

Besides, in the example in that blog, it seems like I have to connect my own web application to ESB to validate the token. Is there any API I can use in my app to validate the token directly with the Identity Server? Or how should I connect my Jsp web app to the ESB?

Answer (score 0):

In your client code, please change following

private static final String ESB = "http://127.0.0.1:8280/";

To

private static final String ESB = "http://127.0.0.1:8282/";